# Can't make keras work with tensorflow-gpu

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I can't seem to make Keras work with TensorFlow-GPU, whenever I try to use it this exception pops up, "Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install Tensorflow". Does anyone know how to solve this?

OS: Windows 10

Comment: open a python shell and import tensorflow, it probably fails and that is the real reason why keras does not work.

Comment: Check your pip version. Older pip version don't install newer versions of the package

Comment: I prefer to install teensorflow with Conda if you have anaconda installed. Reason is it installs the Cuda Toolkit and  Cudnn. Pip does not.

Comment: @Dr Snoopy I have TensorFlow installed so that's not it, I'm used to installing the CPU version of TensorFlow but I'm struggling to make Keras work with with the GPU version

Comment: Please read my comment again, I am telling you to import tensorflow to see if any errors come up

Comment: @theastronomist the problem isn't installing the libs, I've got both Keras and the GPU version of tensorflow installed but keras won't work with it. it's just asking me for the tensorflow version 2.2 even though I've got tensorflow-gpu installed

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy I can import it without any problems

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow did you install?

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy tensorflow-gpu version 2.3.0